# What difference between Python 2 and Python 3 is causing this error?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7, psycopg2

What is the reasoning behind why this works in Python 2.7, but does not in Python 3? I'm using psycopg2 to insert values into a table, but the cursor is having a hard time with column2 in my pandas dataframe.

```
In [1]: df.info()
<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
RangeIndex: 11565 entries, 0 to 11564
Data columns (total 3 columns):
column1    11565 non-null object
column2    11565 non-null int64
column3    11565 non-null object
dtypes: int64(1), object(2)
memory usage: 271.1+ KB

# Python 2.7
cur = conn.cursor()

# pass table values 
vals = [cur.mogrify("(%s, %s, %s)", (x, y, z)) for x, y, z in zip(df['column1'], df['column2'],df['column3'])]
# Great!
```

--

```
# Python 3.5
cur = conn.cursor()

# pass table values 
vals = [cur.mogrify("(%s, %s, %s)", (x, y, z)) for x, y, z in zip(df['column1'], df['column2'],df['column3'])]

<ipython-input-2-ee4818a2eb52> in <listcomp>(.0)
      1 # pass table values
----> 2 vals = [cur.mogrify("(%s, %s, %s)", (x, y, z)) for x, y, z in zip(df['column1'], df['column2'],df['column3'])]

ProgrammingError: can't adapt type 'numpy.int64'
```

Does this have to do with different versions of psycopg2 itself or the underlying Python version? Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

I think the relevant diference is in NumPy's automatic mapping from native Python types to its internal types. From [their docs](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/arrays.scalars.html#built-in-scalar-types):

> **Warning**: The `int_` type does not inherit from the `int` built-in under Python 3, because type `int` is no longer a fixed-width integer type.

Somewhere in your code you're getting a values out of a numpy result, and in Python 2 the values are native `int`s, but in Python 3 they may still be `numpy.int64`s because it didn't know what to convert them to. I'm not sure how you would fix that.

Comment: This seems like the appropriate answer. [Psycopg2 doesn't seem to support the numpy int64 type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41449501/error-inserting-values-to-db-with-psycopg2-module). Also see [this relevant GitHub page](https://github.com/musically-ut/psycopg2_numpy_ext).